# The class 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' was not found in the chain configured namespaces XXX

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have read the the other questions concerning this issue but have not come across a solution as of yet.

I get the following error message:

> The class 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' was not found in the chain configured >namespaces ZfcUser\Entity, Common\Entity, Employment\Entity, Intern\Entity, >Team\Entity, PurchaseRequest\Entity.

I have a HolidayEntity, HolidayController, HolidayService.

Adding a holiday works, but when I try to remove a holiday the error pops up.
I pass the holiday id from to controller to the service, which then fetches the associated object and runs the doctrine 2 removeEntity command.

I am unsure as to how to tackle the problem at the moment.

Controller code:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    $holidayId = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    try {  
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('holidayService')->removeHoliday($holidayId);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage() . '<br>' . $e->getTraceAsString());
    }
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('holiday/list');
}
```

Service Code:

```
public function removeHoliday($holidayId)
{
    try{
    $holiday = $this->findOneHolidayById($holidayId);
    $this->removeEntity($holiday);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}

protected function removeEntity($entity)
{
    $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

The code breaks in the "$this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity)" method.

Comment: what is passed as $entity?

Comment: can you post the code for the method `findOneHolidayById ` ?  are you sure the id passed from the route exists?

Comment: The id exists, findOneHolidayById returns a holiday object when the id is passed into it. So that method cannot be the issue.

Comment: I overlooked the var_dump details as being a entitymanger entity and not as a holiday entity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error you are getting relates to Doctrine not being able to find an Entity called `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`, which is clearly wrong.

My guess is that somewhere (perhaps in the `getEntityManager()` method) you are passing an instance of the entity manager to the entity manager.

For example

```
$entityManager = new EntityManager();
$entity = new EntityManager();
$entityManager->remove($entity);
```

Comment: That guess was spot on. @Matteo, you were on the right track, the id passed was right and the return from the method was wrong since i was returning the entitymanager instead of the result object.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexP's answer is correct. To be specific, this is one of common mistakes when using doctrine:

**Repository.php**

```php
public function findBySomething($something)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
       ->where('e.something = :something')
       ->setParameter('something', $something);
}
```

**Somewhere else**

```php
// WRONG USE CASE

$entity = $this->repository->findBySomething('foo');
$this->entityManager->remove($entity);
```

**Correction**

```php
$entity = $this->repository->findBySomething('foo')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getFirstResult();
$this->entityManager->remove($entity);
```